# In my output the new line is not sowing when used the '/n' in f-string inside a function

Tags: python, newline

[image]

```
import requests

def get_news(topic, from_date, to_date, language="en", api_key="c0c867e37d3f4fd09af31a177ff6472b"):
    url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle={topic}&from={from_date}&to={to_date}&sortBy=popularity&language={language}&apiKey={api_key}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.json()
    articles = content["articles"]
    results = []
    for article in articles:
        results.append(f' "TITLE:\n", {article["title"]},"\nSOURCE:\n", {article["source"]}')
    return results
print(get_news(topic="stock", from_date="2023-5-27",to_date="2023-5-29"))
```

Comment: You are printing the list not the strings

Comment: You print `result`, which is a list. When print list, the elements of list are visualised by their `repr()`

Comment: Change it to `print(*get_news(...))` or `print(" ".join(get_news(...)))`